# JavaScript не читает часть кода

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь написать игру на запоминание, но часть кода просто не читается. Я не слишком хорошо разбираюсь в JavaScript, из-за чего ошибка может быть очевидной.

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".memory_card");
let CardFliped = false;
let firstCard,secondCard;
const CardFlip = e => {
    const target = e.target.parentElement;
    console.log(e.target.parentElement);
    target.classList.add("flip");
if(!CardFliped){
    firstCard = target.dataset.card;
    CardFliped = true;
}else{
    secondCard = target.dataset.card;
    CardFliped = false;
    
    }
};
const checkdata = () =>{        //НЕ ЧИТАЕТ ЭТО
    console.log(firstCard);
    console.log(secondCard);
    if(firstCard === secondCard){
        firstCard.removeEventListener("click", CardFlip);
        secondCard.removeEventListener("click", CardFlip);
     console.log("WOW");
    }
    else{
        console.log("no");
    }
};

cards.forEach(card =>{
    card.addEventListener("click", CardFlip);
});
```

Comment: Вы объявляете функцию `checkdata()`, но не видно, где вы её используете.

Comment: Если я вписываю checkdata(), то выдаёт такую ошибку:
 ```file.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of undefined
    at checkdata (file.js:21)
    at file.js:29```

Comment: Это означает, что вы вызываете checkdata до того, как firstCard или secondCard будут определены. То есть или до вызова CardFlip, или после того, как только один из условных блоков сработает, а в другом переменная так и не будет определена.